# How to update view after call 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);' with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I've an Angular controller with an Array $scope.positions=[].

This array shown in html with

```
<tr ng-repeat="position in positions">
          <td>{{position.latitude}}</td>
          <td>{{position.longitude}}</td>
        </tr>
```

I call to `'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);` when I click in a button.

The success function is:

```
function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    $scope.positions.push(new Position(latitude,longitude));
}
```

where  Position is a object:

```
function Position(latitud,longitud){
    this.latitud=latitud;
    this.longitud=longitud;
    this.toGoogle=function(){
      return new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud);
    }
```

}

When I click above a button the variable $scope.positions add the new Position but the view don't update with the new data. If I click again, the table show the previous data but not the current data.

I suppose that the binding in Angular will be execute after a Event but if You have a callback, for example, an Ajax call you should paint the data with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually trigger the digest loop.

Change it to:

```
function success(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.positions.push(new Position(latitude, longitude));
  });
}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

Comment: or you can use $timeout or  $evalAsync  for better performance http://www.panda-os.com/2015/01/angularjs-apply-digest-and-evalasync/#.VKlWXfnd9B0

Comment: `$timeout` uses both `setTimeout` and `$apply` internally, so it's not better for performance and is used for other purposes. Performance-wise `$evalAsync` is most often used when dealing with directives that query the DOM layout as part of their linking logic.